# GridView Error: Sql Error HResult=-2146232060, String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net grid view to display database table data onto my website. It works fine. However the edit button works sometimes and sometimes gives me an error. how can i get it to ignore errors.I also have a select button that redirects to a new page where i can edit the row and that also behaves the same.

Here is the c # code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Reporters_Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void cameraman_gridview_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Label2.Text = reporters_gridview.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
        Session["id"] = reporters_gridview.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
        Response.Redirect("Reporters_Search.aspx");

       //"You selected " + reporters_gridview.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text + ".";
    }
    protected void btn_newrep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Reporters_Form.aspx");
    }
}
```

Here is the html

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Reporters_Main.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reporters_Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 90%;
            height: 615px;
            margin-right: 0px;
        }
        .style2
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .style6
        {
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-align: center;
            height: 10px;
        }
        .style7
        {
            height: 5%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body link="#ffffff">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table class="style1" align="center" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="style6" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="White">
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#4A3C8C" 
                    style="padding: 10px" height="10%">
                    <strong style="font-size: 32px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF;">REPORTERS
                    DETAILS</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 0px; text-align: right" align="center" 
                    valign="middle" bgcolor="#E7E7FF" height="5%">
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_newrep" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" 
                        Text="Add New" Width="10%" onclick="btn_newrep_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top;" align="center" 
                    valign="top" height="70%" 
                    width="100%">
                    <asp:GridView ID="reporters_gridview" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" 
                        BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
                        DataKeyNames="Reporter_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_Reporters" 
                        GridLines="Horizontal" Width="100%" Height="100%" PageSize="20" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="cameraman_gridview_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Reporter_ID" HeaderText="Reporter_ID" 
                                SortExpression="Reporter_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True">
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Reporter_Name" HeaderText="Reporter_Name" 
                                SortExpression="Reporter_Name" >
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Reporter_Email" HeaderText="Reporter_Email" 
                                SortExpression="Reporter_Email" >
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Reporter_Mobile" HeaderText="Reporter_Mobile" 
                                SortExpression="Reporter_Mobile" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" 
                                ShowEditButton="True">
                            <ItemStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" ForeColor="White" />
                            </asp:CommandField>
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                        <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_Reporters" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IngestConnectionString %>" 

                        SelectCommand="SELECT [Reporter_ID], [Reporter_Name], [Reporter_Email], [Reporter_Mobile] FROM [Reporter] ORDER BY [Reporter_ID], [Reporter_Name]" 
                        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
                        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Reporter] WHERE [Reporter_ID] = @original_Reporter_ID AND (([Reporter_Name] = @original_Reporter_Name) OR ([Reporter_Name] IS NULL AND @original_Reporter_Name IS NULL)) AND (([Reporter_Email] = @original_Reporter_Email) OR ([Reporter_Email] IS NULL AND @original_Reporter_Email IS NULL)) AND (([Reporter_Mobile] = @original_Reporter_Mobile) OR ([Reporter_Mobile] IS NULL AND @original_Reporter_Mobile IS NULL))" 
                        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Reporter] ([Reporter_Name], [Reporter_Email], [Reporter_Mobile]) VALUES (@Reporter_Name, @Reporter_Email, @Reporter_Mobile)" 
                        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
                        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Reporter] SET [Reporter_Name] = @Reporter_Name, [Reporter_Email] = @Reporter_Email, [Reporter_Mobile] = @Reporter_Mobile WHERE [Reporter_ID] = @original_Reporter_ID AND (([Reporter_Name] = @original_Reporter_Name) OR ([Reporter_Name] IS NULL AND @original_Reporter_Name IS NULL)) AND (([Reporter_Email] = @original_Reporter_Email) OR ([Reporter_Email] IS NULL AND @original_Reporter_Email IS NULL)) AND (([Reporter_Mobile] = @original_Reporter_Mobile) OR ([Reporter_Mobile] IS NULL AND @original_Reporter_Mobile IS NULL))">
                        <DeleteParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Reporter_ID" Type="Int32" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Reporter_Name" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Reporter_Email" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Reporter_Mobile" Type="String" />
                        </DeleteParameters>
                        <InsertParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Reporter_Name" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Reporter_Email" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Reporter_Mobile" Type="String" />
                        </InsertParameters>
                        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Reporter_Name" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Reporter_Email" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Reporter_Mobile" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Reporter_ID" Type="Int32" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Reporter_Name" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Reporter_Email" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Reporter_Mobile" Type="String" />
                        </UpdateParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#4A3C8C" class="style7" 
                    width="100%">
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the error . ( I only get this error sometimes. Most of the time it is ok and it updates the table )

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232060
  Message=String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  Class=16
  LineNumber=1
  Number=8152
  Procedure=""
  Server=.
  State=4
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at Search_Reporters.btn_Save_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Gerard\Desktop\Ingest\Reporters_Search.aspx.cs:line 61
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense without further details or code.

Comment: Show code, provide exact error details so your question can be answered

Comment: Message in error explains the problem that one of the value of you table column is exceed to its original lengths. Check the column with and increase the length of the column.

Comment: Thanks Sain it was just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

determine the cause of the error and attempt to "fix" it, or alternatively set conditions or a try catch to prevent error showing (last resort, would attempt the first)

Comment: Please review the error and let me know how i can fix it. Thanks for your help

Comment: error says that the "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated". I presume what you entering exceeds that maximum field length in your table. either extend the field length in the table or restrict the input length.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some proper codes of your error.

Comment: that's a comment, not an answer

Comment: I have provided the error details. thanks for your help